# Alcatel-Lucent BGP Default-Originate

Tags: bgp, alcatel-lucent-7750

I've been looking around trying to find the ALU version of Cisco's "default-originate" but have been unable to find it.  Is there a way to generate a zero route towards a BGP neighbor without having to redistribute a static/dynamic zero route into the BGP table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure there is no such command or feature in TiMOS. The one way you can emulate such behavior is with a static blackhole-route, a prefix-list and a policy-statement. It's not what you asked but still pretty decent. Sample configuration:

```
configure router
    static-route 0.0.0.0/0 black-hole
    static-route ::/0 black-hole
    policy-options
        prefix-list "default-only"
            prefix 0.0.0.0/0 exact
            prefix ::/0 exact
        exit
        policy-statement "default-originate"
            entry 10
                from
                    protocol static
                    prefix-list "default-only"
                    family ipv4 ipv6
                exit
                action accept
                exit
            exit
            default-action next-policy
        exit
```

Now you can apply that policy as an export policy in BGP group level before your normal export policy.

edit: Of course advertising default to your CE device without knowing if you have upstream connectivity could be considered as poor design. One way to enhance the configuration above is to make prefix-list of known dynamically learned prefixes from your network (or internet) and make those static blackhole routes conditional. This can be achieved with `prefix-list <name> [all|none]` parameter in the static-route context. By default, logical OR is used.